# How to setup Blender for arduino comunication?

Tags: python, serial-port, blender, pyserial

Hello I want to connect my Arduino device to Blender. I'm using Blender 2.78c and Python 3.6. I have no problem sending data from my Arduino device to a PC with a simple Python program like this:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)
while 1:
try:
    print(ser.readline())
    time.sleep(1)
except ser.SerialTimeoutException:
    print('Data could not be read')
time.sleep(1)
```

But I want to for my Arduino device to talk with Blender.
When I try to run the same program in Blender I get this error:

- ImportError: No module named 'serial'

[image]

How to make "serial" module work in Blender?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that I found was to install Python 3.5.2 to match the Python version of the Blender as shown in the Blender console.

[image]

So I deleted /Blender/2.78/python so that the Blender would use Python on my system rather then Python that comes with Blender

Answer (score 0):

i did copy the folder "serial" & "pyserial-xxxxx" and " serial-0.0xxxx" from program/python/python37-xx/Lib/site-packages  to the  blender/2.79/python/lib/site-packages   and it works now.